# VB.net If statements across different forms not working

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I've been encountering the same problem over and over with some IF statements. One one form I've got this:

```
If KarlConvo = 4 Then
    MsgBox("Karl: Wow man. I overheard everything. I don't like your methods but it did work. Have this man. I can't wait until she approaches my sexy self")
    MsgBox("You have obtained the SANDWICH")
    PlayerProfileMale.tpbSandwich.Visible = True
    PlayerProfileMale.lblSandwich.Visible = True
    Form2.lblFact3C2.Visible = True
    KarlConvo = 5
    TobyConvo = 4
    PlayerProfileMale.EatButton = True
End If
```

The code above happens after a msgbox pops up. It should allow for a 'Eat' button to appear on another form. The IF statement on that form is:

```
If EatButton = True Then
    btnEat.Visible = True
End If
```

Well the problem is that the button is not showing on my second form even though the only condition it has is for the EatButton variable (which is a Public Property) to be true. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not clear on the scope of EatButton. Show more of the context?

Comment: Try to look at 4 lines before. What is the difference between that line and the EatButton?

Comment: To display the btnEat button that is within the PlayerProfileMale form from another form, you must do PlayerProfileMale.btnEat.Show

Comment: How are you initializing your PlayerProfileMale form. Be careful that you are not using the default instance.

Comment: @Aprendiendo.Net Thank you very much Aprendiendo. I didn't know it was as simple as just typing PlayerProfileMale.btnEat.Show . It works perfectly now. I guess I can just disregard the EatButton variable from the PlayerProfileMale form now.

Comment: Right. From any form other than ***PlayerProfileMale*** Form (because this Form contains ***btnEat*** button) you must use `PlayerProfileMale.btnEat.Show`. And within the ***PlayerProfileMale*** form you can use `Me.btn.show` or simply `btn.show`, because ***btnEat*** button is in the ***PlayerProfileMale*** Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to check:

1. Show, paint, or reload the `PlayerProfileMale` form after you assign `PlayerProfileMale.EatButton = True`. Trigger an event that causes the `If EatButton` statement to be executed.
2. Make sure you're addressing the proper instance of `PlayerProfileMale` when you assign `PlayerProfileMale.EatButton = True`. This shouldn't normally be a problem, but can be if you create an instance of the form and another instance is created (or already open) when you make the assignment.